# how to make a condition with reactjs in a map?

Tags: reactjs

thanks in advance for your help but I'm trying to make a condition,

if map result is undefined then it displays an alert, but I can't get it to work: /

here is the code:

```
 function Results({ results, openPopup }) {
 return (
     <div>
         <section className="results">
             {results.map(result => ( 
                 result === undefined 
                 ? (<Alert variant="danger"> This is a alert—check it out!</Alert>)
                 : (<Result key={result.imdbID} result={result} openPopup={openPopup}/>) 
                   
             ))}

         </section>
         
     </div>
 )
```

}

Comment: What kind of error did you get ?

Comment: Are you sure that result is undefined and not an empty object {}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `results` an array that has elements `undefined` or is `results===undefined`? If `results` is undefined and not `[undefined]`:

```
function Results({ results, openPopup }) {
return (
    <div>
        <section className="results">
            {results===undefined?
                <Alert variant="danger"> This is a alert—check it out!</Alert>
                : results.map(result=><Result key={result.imdbID} result={result} 
                                        openPopup={openPopup}/> )
                  
            ))}

        </section>

        
    </div>
)
```